# "Reset" button won't work unless it refreshes page, and gives me an error otherwise (React.JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm working in React.JS, and I'm trying to make something like an input field, where a user can enter a number of their choice, and it will show up in the text.

I decided to add a "Reset to zero" button, as an extension.

```
             <div>
                Count: {this.state.value}
                <form>
                <input type="number" value = {this.state.value} onChange = {this.inputChange}/>
                <br/>
                <button onClick = {this.reset}>reset to zero</button>
                </form>     
            </div>
```

It works, but it refreshes the page every time it does so.

I read online, and I decided to add "type=button" to my button as so:

```
<button type="button" onClick = {this.reset}>reset to zero</button>
```

When I run my code again, it still increments fine, but when I click the button, nothing happens, and when I try to increment it again, I get an error, "TypeError: this.setState is not a function".

The error is coming from this method:

```
inputChange = event => {
        this.setState ({value: event.target.value})
    }
```

I know where the error is coming from, but I don't know why it happened, or how to fix it (note that I'm also a beginner at JavaScript and React.JS)

I hope someone can help me.

Here's my code in entirety, for reference.

```
class Slider extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: 0
        }
    }
    inputChange = event => {
        this.setState ({value: event.target.value})
    }
    reset = () => {
        this.setState = ({
            count: 0
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Count: {this.state.value}
                <form>
                <input type="number" value = {this.state.value} onChange = {this.inputChange}/>
                <br/>
                <button type = "button"onClick = {this.reset}>reset to zero</button>
                </form>     
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Thank you guys, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason nothing happens on reset and you are getting that error on input change, is that you are reassigning `this.setState` in your reset function rather than calling it. Also, you are setting `count` instead of `value`, which would lead to the wrong state being set.

This is what your reset function should be:

```
reset = () => {
    this.setState ({
        value: 0
    })
}
```

When you call `this.setState`, React will trigger a re-render in your component with the new state.

That is currently not happening when you click reset. On your subsequent call to inputChange, `this.setState` has been reassigned with an object, and is no longer callable, throwing that error.

Comment: Ohhhh, so my mistake was I was trying to assign a new value in my input change method, by using the equal sign. I got rid of the equal sign, and my code works fine now. Thank you for helping me realize my mistake!

Comment: No problem! Happy to have been able to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your button like this:

```
<button type = "button"onClick = {this.reset.bind(this)}>reset to zero</button>
```

This will force the method to execute being `this` the scope.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue because @Samy Rashed is using class properties for reset and inputChange. Therefore, `this` is already bound to the component.

Comment: @CoreyLarson right, just saw your answer and makes more sense

Comment: Yeah, @CoreyLarson handled the issue for me well. Nonetheless, thank you for trying to help!